# Processing array and inserting in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
Array
(
[pid] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 3
    )

[price] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 20
    )

[qty] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 1
    )

)
```

i have an outcome of the above array from some processing. with this i need to update to database like below table

```
pid price qty
2   20    2
3   20    1
```

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: So Update it and let us know if you run into an issue ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
while( $i < count( $YourArray['pid']) ) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tableName`(`pid`, `price`, `qty`) VALUES( ?, ?, ? )";
    $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute(
        array(
            $YourArray['pid'][$i],
            $YourArray['price'][$i],
            $YourArray['qty'][$i]
        )
    );
    $i++;
}
```

Where, I used the [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) method of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<amount;i++){
    echo $array['pid'][i];
    echo $array['price'][i];
    echo $array['qty'][i]; 
}
```

Where amount must be a `count` of the amount of rows you have

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$array = array("pid" => array(2,3),"price" => array(20,20),"qty" => array(2,1));
array_unshift($array, null);
$res   = call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

loop this array and add to DB - So that you can add two entries in DB

Comment: How does this update a database? He obviosly already has the output in an array.

Comment: I just processed the array so that using a loop he can update to DB

Answer (score 0):

this is a wrong way of doing it, i would use an indexed array, and then build a foreach loop that will handle each 1 separately, something like:

```
$values = array();
$values[] = array(
                  'pid' => 2,
                  'price' => 20,
                  'qty' => 2
                 );

$values[] = array(
                  'pid' => 3,
                  'price' => 20,
                  'qty' => 1
                  );
```

and from this then build a foreach loop and run each query there

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
   $query = "insert into blah 
              set pid = " . $value['pid'] . ",
              price = " . $value['price'] . ",
              qty = " . $value['qty'] . ";";

   mysql_query($query);
}
```